# Vue CLI delete the outputDir folder during serve

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

I'm trying to use VueCLI and delete the output directory during serve, so that I can use this in my php files and determine whether to load dist assets or load via `localhost:8080`.

So in my `vue.config.js` I have:

```
module.exports = {
  outputDir:'web',
  configureWebpack: config => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
        console.log("its serve") // this logs
        // here delete the outputDir
    }
  }
}
```

How do i delete a folder using the VueCLI since by default during serve my app is never deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [rimraf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf) to remove the `dist` directory.

```js
const rimraf = require("rimraf");

module.exports = {
  outputDir: 'web',
  configureWebpack: config => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
        rimraf.sync(config.outputDir);
        // rimraf.sync('web')
    }
  }
};
```

As an alternative you can append the rimraf to your `serve` script.

```json
// package.json

"scripts": {
    "serve": "rimraf web && vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
}
```

Comment: Thanks i like the package.json option and also it works